# Style guide: how to not get into a mess in a big project

Tags: python, django, module

**Django==2.2.5**

In the examples below two custom filters and two auxiliary functions. 
It is a fake example, not a real code.

Two problems with this code:

1. When a project becomes big I forget what aux functions I have already written. Not to mention team programming. What is the solution here? To organize a separate module for functions that can be imported? And sort them alphabetically?
2. Some functions from here may be reused outside this package, and some may not. Say, the combine function seems to be reusable, while `get_salted_str` is definitely for this module only. I think that it is better to distinguish between functions that may be imported and those that may not. Is it better to use underline symbol to mark unimported functions? Like this: `_get_salted_str`. This may ease the first problem a bit.
3. Does Django style guide or any other pythonic style guide mention solutions to the two above mentioned problems?

My code example:

```
def combine(str1, str2):
    return "{}_{}".format(str1, str2)

def get_salted_str(str):
    SALT = "slkdjghslkdjfghsldfghaaasd"
    return combine(str, SALT)

@register.filter
def get_salted_string(str):    
    return combine(str, get_salted_str(str))


@register.filter
def get_salted_peppered_string(str):
    salted_str = get_salted_str(str)
    PEPPER = "1234128712908369735619346"

    return "{}_{}".format(PEPPER, salted_str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to go about this, so here is the way I always handle this:

**1. Reusable functions in a project**

First and foremost: Documentation. When working in a big team you definitely need to document reusable function. 
Second, packages. When creating a lot of auxiliary/helper functions, that might have a use outside the current module or app, it can be useful to bundle them all together. I often create a 'base' or 'utils' package in my Django project where I bundle all sorts of functions.

[The django.contrib package is a pretty good example of all sorts of helper packages bundled into one.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/#humanize)

My rule of thumb is, if I find that I reuse some function/piece of code, I move it to my utils package, and if it's related to something else in that package, I bundle them together. That makes it pretty easy to keep track of all the functions there are.

**2. Private functions**

Python doesn't really have private members, but the generally accepted way to 'mark' a member as private is to add an underscore, like `_get_salted_str`

**3. Style guide**

With regards to auxiliary functions, I'm not aware of any styleguide.

'Private' members : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Answer (score 2):

> 1. When a project becomes big I forget what aux functions I have already written. Not to mention team programming. What is the solution here?

Good documentation and proper modularization.

> To organize a separate module for functions that can be imported?

Technically, *all* functions (except of course nested ones) can be imported. Now I assume you meant: "for functions that are meant to be imported from other modules", but even then, it doesn't mean much - it often happens that a function primarily intended for "internal use" (helper function used within the same module) later becomes useful for other modules.

Also, the proper way to regroup function is not based on whether those are for internal or public use (this is handled by prefixing 'internal use only' functions with a single leading underscore), but on how those functions are related.

NB: I use the term "function" because that's how you phrased your question, but this applies to all other names (classes etc).

> And sort them alphabetically?

Bad idea IMHO - it doesn't make any sense from a function POV, and can cause issue when merging diverging branches.

> 2. Some functions from here may be reused outside this package, and some may not. Say, the combine function seems to be reusable, while "get_salted_str" is definitely for this module only. I think that it is better to distinguish between functions that may be imported and those that may not. Is it better to use underline symbol to mark unimported functions? Like this: _get_salted_str. This may ease the first problem a bit.

Why would you prevent `get_salted_str` from being imported by another module actually ?

'protected' (single leading underscore) names are for implementation parts that the module's client code should not mess with nor even be aware of - this is called "encapsulation" -, the goal being to allow for implementation changes that won't break the client code.

In your example, `get_salted_str()` is a template filter, so it's obviously part of your package's public API.

OTHO, `combine` really looks like an implementation detail - the fact that some unrelated code in another package may need to combine two strings with the same separator seems mostly accidental, and if you expose `combine` as part of the module's API you cannot change it's implementation anyway. This is typically an implementation function as far as I can tell from your example (and also it's so trivial that it really doesn't warrant being exposed as ar as I'm concerned).

As a more general level: while avoiding duplication is a very audable goal, you must be careful of overdoing it. Some duplication is actually "accidental" - at some point in time, two totally unrelated parts of the code have a few lines in common, but for totally different reasons, and the forces that may lead to a change in one point of the code are totally unrelated to the other part. So before factoring out seemingly duplicated code, ask yourself if this code is doing the same thing *for the same reasons* and whether changing this code in one part should affect the other part too.

> 3. Does Django style guide or any other pythonic style guide mention solutions to the two above mentioned problems?

This is nothing specific to Django, nor even to Python. Writing well organized code relies on the same heuristics whatever the language: you want high cohesions (all functions / classes etc in a same module should be related and provide solutions to the same problems) and low coupling (a module should depend on as few other modules as possible).

NB: I'm talking about "modules" here but the same rules hold for packages (a package is kind of a super-module) or classes (a class is a kind of mini-module too - except that you can have multiple instances of it).

Now it must be said that proper modularisation - like proper naming etc - IS hard. It takes time and experience (and a lot of reflexion) to develop (no pun intended but...) a "feel" for it, and even then you often find yourself reorganizing things quite a bit during your project's lifetime.  And, well, there almost always be some messy area somewhere, because sometimes finding out where a given feature really belongs is a bit of wild guess (hint: look for modules or packages named "util" or "utils" or "helpers" - those are usually where the dev regrouped stuff that didn't clearly belong anywhere else).